# Android: How to pass Intent via startActivity() to a running Activity?

Tags: android

Say `MyService` and `MyClient` are both running, although `MyClient` is currently in the background. If `MyService` sends an Intent to `MyClient` via:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MYService.this, MyClient.class);
i.setAction("com.test.MyService.ACTION_SERVICE");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

How do I get this Intent in MyClient? Running this code triggers onResume() in `MyClient`, but because it's already running, calling `getIntent()` returns the Intent that initially created MyClient, which is always `android.intent.action.MAIN`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

override onNewIntent() and make sure you flag the intent so that it doesn't start a new instance of your activity